# Limiting CI queue size to 1 to make Bitbucket's pipeline jobs blocking

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a hard time searching for this as I'm getting lot of results regarding the paralerism of the steps inside the pipeline itself, which is not my problem (as I'm concerned about parallelism one level above the pipeline steps). I was looking through google/so and Atlassian documentation, but probably I'm searching for it under the wrong term.

I have two steps in my pipeline, build HTML files and deploy them. The deployment just does git push of the final HTML files to the final reposity. This works very well, but my concern is that if I would do by accident multiple commits and pushes quickly one after the other. Then depending on their content, they might finish in a different order than they started and doing an out-of-order deployment, which I want to avoid.

There might be more robust ways of deployment, but because this is a fairly simple project, I wouldn't want to overcomplicate it and I would like to keep deployment as it is. And just limit my pipeline CI to running one job/task at the time and if I will push faster than it can build then just block/wait for the previous one to finish.

In essence, I want my CI queue size to be just 1 job to make the incoming jobs triggered by commits blocking instead of asynchronous. Is there some way or workaround to achieve something like that and make the jobs blocking?